# Is there a Stack Exchange site related to questions on using LibreOffice?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I had a question on how to do certain thing in the [LibreOffice Writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Writer), and it was deleted as "not related to programming".

Is there a Stack Exchange site that is related to problem with "using" the tool?

Comment: Side note, [meta.se] is a better site for asking what site is appropriate for specific types of questions. [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) would be appropriate for asking if a question is on-topic on [so], but not for recommendations for if something is on-topic elsewhere (in the community).

Comment: Considering your (closed) questions starts off with *"Is there some extensive tutorial on how to correctly work with numbered items combined with other nested bullet list?"* I would suggest that your question is off-topic for [su] too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the question [Super User](https://superuser.com/) might be the place to ask. They have tags for [[libreoffice]](https://superuser.com/tags/libreoffice/info) and [[libreoffice-writer]](https://superuser.com/tags/libreoffice-writer/info).

Do make sure to check what [is on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) or [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) for the site as well as the tag guidance.